# How to get grails to use version 2.2 when 2.3 installed

Tags: grails

I have installed Grails version 2.2 and 2.3 (among others)

How can I tell grails to use 2.2 for a project?

When i try:

```
grails set-version 2.2
```

It fails to find dependencies, and stops.  I already set app.grails.version=2.2.0 in the application.properties file, but when i run grails  it shows 2.3.3, and fails.

Comment: I just found I can change my path, to point to the 2.2 version, and that is working, is that the only/best way?

Comment: in my test server I have a couple of grails versions. In the deploy.sh for each project I define `$GRAILS_HOME` to point to the specific installation. This is pretty easy and straight-forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found GVM to be pretty useful. Inspired by other environment managers, it lets you easily switch the version used.

http://gvmtool.net/

```
curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash
gvm install grails 2.2.0
gvm use 2.2.0
grails clean
grails run-app
```

Answering the prompts along the way. Very useful if you have multiple versions of grails for different projects.